# How can I prevent users commits if any file is old

Tags: svn

I have a problem with subversion.

Lets say there are two developers (1 and 2) committing to a repository. The repository contains 3 files A, B and C. Both developers update their local environments. The developer 1 modifies the files A and B, and commits. Later, The developer 2 modifies the file C and commits.

Subversion will allow the developer 2 to commit, but I would prefer not.

Is there any way of configuring subversion for not allowing to commit in this scenario?

Regards.

Comment: What is exactly wrong with committing file C separately from A and B ?

Comment: The usual protocol for working with svn (with source code) is to do an update-rebuild-commit. What you want to do is *enforce* this? Do I understand correctly?

Comment: You can ask Developer 1 to lock files ABC, so noone can touch them until he unlocks them

Comment: @Krom: Before commiting we run a test battery, and I want to ensure the code testes is exactly the same one that will be in the repo once commited.

Comment: @Anders: Yes. That what I want. To enforce it. I think you understood correctly.

Comment: @Krom(2): I would preffer other option than explicit locking. Do you know any?

Comment: An issue with enforcing it is that once the number of concurrent users reaches a certain number people will have to update-rebuild-test-commit several times before they commit. if the build/test cycle is long enough you may *never* be able to commit! This is why you usually have to be pragmatic here, and let the CI server detect any issues while the developers keep working.

Comment: @Anders(2): Thanks. I understand the problem you're talking about. Right now we are just 10 developers, so project scalability is not really an issue.

Comment: ok. I'm fairly sure there is nothing built into svn that will let you do this, although it may be possible to script using commit hooks. What problem are you trying to solve? Is it that you never want a build error on the CI server?

Comment: @Anders(3): Seems like if you were reading my mind :). As you well say, the problem I am trying to solve is not having to build an error at the integration server. I think I will take the option of configuring the continuous integration to roll back any changeset that breaks the build.